# Explode jquery - принцип действия эффекта

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript, html

Как работает эффект explode в jquery

по ккому принципу элемент разбивается на маленькие элементы?

http://jqueryui.com/hide/

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js